# Converting Json to .NET Object collection

Tags: json, wcf, silverlight, wcf-data-services

As part of my WCF service, i convert my DataTable into a JSON. On client side, I want to able to convert this JSON response into a .NET collection. I want to be able to keep it dynmaic, and bind it to a data grid. I am trying figure out the best way to do this. Thanks jay

Comment: I want to be able to read the name/value pair and create objects based on that. In other words, dont want to use classes on the client side as WCF service returns JSON for any SQL.

Comment: Dont want to use classes on the client side ..what do you mean by this?

Comment: Basically, dont want to create an object on the client side after deserializing JSON. Instead load the response into an anonymous object and possibly get the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Define a collection and a class whose properties match the JSON data - then use the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class. Then just bind your grid to the collection:

```
class ACollection
{
    public IEnumerable<SomeClass> SomeClassList { get; set; }
}

class SomeClass
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
}


JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
ACollection list = jsSerializer.Deserialize<ACollection>(jsonString);
```